# This value of type "ComObject" has no property named "__Item". when upgrade to v2 using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

[JSONParse](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/93300-what-format-to-store-settings-in/#entry588268)
this work for me in v1

when i upgrade it to v2

```
JSON_parse(jsonStr) {
    SC := ComObject("ScriptControl")
    SC.Language := "JScript"
    jsCode :=
    (
    "function arrangeForAhkTraversing(obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Array) {
            for(var i=0 ; i<obj.length ; ++i)
                obj[i] = arrangeForAhkTraversing(obj[i]) ;
            return ['array',obj] ;
        } else if(obj instanceof Object) {
            var keys = [], values = [] ;
            for(var key in obj) {
                keys.push(key) ;
                values.push(arrangeForAhkTraversing(obj[key])) ;
            }
            return ['object',[keys,values]] ;
        } else
            return [typeof obj,obj] ;
    }"
    )
    SC.ExecuteStatement(jsCode "; obj=" jsonStr)
    return convertJScriptObj2AHK(SC.Eval("arrangeForAhkTraversing(obj)"))
}

convertJScriptObj2AHK(jsObj) {
    if (jsObj[0]=="object") {
        obj := {}, keys := jsObj[1][0], values := jsObj[1][1]
        loop keys.length
            obj[keys[A_Index-1]] := convertJScriptObj2AHK(values[A_Index-1])
        return obj
    } else if (jsObj[0] == "array") {
        array := []
        loop  jsObj[1].length
            array.Insert(convertJScriptObj2AHK(jsObj[1][A_Index-1]))
        return array
    } else return jsObj[1]
}
```

it says This value of type "ComObject" has no property named "__Item"
what can i do?
i guess jsObj[0] is invalid
how to solve this problem